# SQL Server 2008 - Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to compile this code I receive an error message saying

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

How can I resolve this issue?

This is the code I am using:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ShopCust] (@sID int)
RETURNS @tbl_Customers table (ShopID int, ShopName varchar(25), NbrCust int)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @tbl_Customers

--Shop ID and Shop Name
SELECT  ShopID , ShopName 
FROM dbo.ShopTbl
WHERE ShopID = @sID 

--Number of Customers for that shop
SELECT NbrCust = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.CustomerTbl
WHERE SupplierID= @sID 

RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: Always specify the columns when using `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for two steps:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_Customers
SELECT  ShopID , ShopName, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.CustomerTbl
    WHERE ShopID = @sID)
FROM dbo.ShopTbl
WHERE ShopID = @sID
```

Comment: And now it is one step no need for it to be a multi statement TVF either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an aggregation:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_Customers(ShopID, ShopName, NbrCust)
    SELECT  ShopID, ShopName, COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.ShopTbl
    WHERE ShopID = @sID 
    GROUP BY ShopID, ShopName;
```

In other words, insert all the values at once.  I don't know what the second `select` is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

The table you are attempting to populate by an INSERT statement is expecting 3 values per record.  Your code indicates you are only selecting 2 values to be inserted in the result table.

Try below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ShopCust] (@sID int)
RETURNS @tbl_Customers table (ShopID int, ShopName varchar(25), NbrCust int)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @tbl_Customers

SELECT  ShopID , ShopName, NbrCust
FROM dbo.ShopTbl                                        AS X
JOIN 
(
SELECT SupplierID , COUNT(*) AS NbrCust
FROM dbo.CustomerTbl
WHERE SupplierID = @sID 
)                                                       AS Y
ON X.ShopID = Y.SupplierID

RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: You'd probably want a left join there. Also you need a `group by` in the derived table though as it only returns a single supplier this can be simplified and no need to return that column at all.